# An error that I am unable to fix in android studio

Tags: android-studio, authentication

I am creating a app which requires log in and register but while coding for the app I encountered a error (I am noob) can anyone please help with it 
Thanks :)

[image]

[image]

Basic idea is to send the entries to login request page which forwards the details to the php using Json which verifies with the DB but encountering this error any more details if needed please comment so that I can upload and reply.

Comment: Unable to add images cause I don't have reputation points.

Comment: The second image requires permission to view. Also, why are you calling `super()` with those parameters? Your class does not  _extend_ another object. The error you are getting is because you are trying to pass those parameters to create an `Object` , but it _doesn't have_ a constructor with those parameters.

Comment: I will check and reply tomorrow sir I am from India it's late night have collage tomorrow thanks for the instantaneous reply :) and new to stack over flow too.

Comment: dude there is no super class, so there suppose to be no super call , don't go to sleep you need to work really hard

Comment: Sure need to haha. I commented update in answer cache stahelis answer check it once sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat hard to tell from your question, but it looks like in your `Login` class, it is looking for an object of type `Request<T>` in the `add()` method, but you supplied it with `LoginRequest` (hence the error message in the second image).

To solve this problem, you need to make your class inherit from a type of `Request<T>` called `StringRequest`: you need to have something like this:

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
```

Without this, the class implicitly chooses `Object` as it's super class (as all java objects do), which doesn't have the parameters you supplied.

So, where you have the following code:

```
LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(Email_id, Password, responseListener);
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
queue.add(loginRequest);
```

`RequestQueue`'s method `add()` takes a parameter *of type* `Request<T>`. `LoginRequest` *is not* a `Request<T>`. This is the reason for your error. `LoginRequest` *needs* to inherit from `StringRequest`. This will fix both errors. If `LoginRequest` inherits from `StringRequest`, then it *is-a* `Request<T>` and then `RequestQueue`'s method `add()` can except `loginRequest` as a parameter.

Comment: This is my first post in stack over flow and didnt expect reply so tried(fixing it myself)  till now and posted while half asleep I will try to find out error if not get back to you with more details sir thanks for time and effort :)

Comment: sir i created a constructor in login class and inherited login class in login request to match login request so the error in the login request class is gone but the old error still remained let me share the code of login class where the add. function is causing error.
[link](https://postimg.org/image/r1x0en7nx/)

https://postimg.org/image/r1x0en7nx/

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood my answer. `LoginReqest` needs to inherit from `Request<T>`. Look at the code I wrote in my answer. you need to have something like `LoginRequest extends Request<T>`.

Comment: Tried that too still the error didn't go and the same error that is there in 1st pic existed...

Comment: Once I inherited login class into log in request that error got solved sir so I thought that is correct and error lies with in login area..

Comment: @user6775626 I added more detail to my answer. Read the last part. It answers your question.

Comment: suggested an edit in answer that solved my issue, thanks alot for your time and efforts sir. :)

Comment: @user6775626 Glad I could help you. Since you are new to Stack Overflow, let me suggest something. Since this answered your question, could you upvote and accept this as the answer? Also, to get answers to questions, make sure to post _actual code_ in your question instead of images. Post the code that is giving the error, and explain what the error is (this _can_ be an image).

Comment: oh next time i get an error will do that :) and i accepted the answer unable to upvote since i do not have enough reputation.